# Send back returned response to ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I have a ajax function in index.php which calls on the page thread.php which returns a JSON response(array). I basically want to parse through that array, display it in a particular html format, take the last value of the last row of that array and send it back in the same ajax call previously mentioned. So that ajax is basically a loop.

```
function returnValue()
{
 $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: "thread.php",
            data: {lastposted : dateposted},
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (json) {
                if(json) {
                    {
                        for (var i = 0, len = json.length; i < len; i++) {

                            var results = json[i];
                            var newDiv = $("<div><img src='" + results[0] +"'/>" + results[2] + results[3] + results[4] + results[5] + "</div><br>");
                           $('#chatContents').append(newDiv);
                           var dateposted = results[5];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }  
        });
}
```

The stored value dateposted needs to be sent as an input when making the ajax call. The default value of dateposted will be 0. 
I am not sure if this can be done. I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this a lot simpler, you don't need to use the extended GET syntax:

```
var returnValue = (function() {
    var dateposted = 0;
    return function() {
        $.get("thread.php", { "lastposted": dateposted }, function(result) {
           // display your chats
           dateposted = result[result.length-1][5];
        }, "json");
    }
})();
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. There were some changes to be made. After making those it worked perfectly. Realised u had edited ur answer and it was the same as the changes i had made. On an additional note, is it possible to constantly refresh the thread.php in the background? Coz currently when i add <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3"> to thread.php, it also returns as response in the ajax call and hence throws off the json array looping.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to your problem is declaring dateposted with a default value outside the function call and use it in the loop to store to store the last value. And have a new Ajax function call. I hope this is want you want.

```
function returnValue()
{

 var dateposted=0;
 $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "GET",
            url: "thread.php",
            data: {lastposted : dateposted},
            dataType: "json",

            success: function (json) {
                if(json) {
                    {
                        for (var i = 0, len = json.length; i < len; i++) {

                            var results = json[i];
                            var newDiv = $("<div><img src='" + results[0] +"'/>" + results[2] + results[3] + results[4] + results[5] + "</div><br>");
                           $('#chatContents').append(newDiv);
                           dateposted = results[5];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }  
        });
}
```

Comment: once it goes back to the top, wont it get reset to 0 again, coz currently that is what i am experiencing. I put in an alert after var dateposted=0; and it always returns 0.

Comment: why will it go to top and and start the function again??.....where are you checking with alert????after for loop or before....if still its showing 0 even after for loop means that its not going inside the loop...are you able to view updated #chatcontents ??

Comment: It's alright. I used the method mentioned on top. And made some adjustments and it works fine now :) As for ur questions, i put the alert after var dateposted=0; Also it was showing my msgs so that means it was going through the loop. I guess after dateposted = results[5]; is set when it finishes the loop and makes the next ajax call, it gets set back to 0

Comment: yea...for every function call the dateposted will be set to 0